# Improving layout and resolution of a network graph in R

Tags: r, igraph

Okay, so I made a plot in R. And I zoomed it as well. Apparently, I am not able to save the zoomed version ( however, it also, doesnt seem to be much helpful ). I am attaching a link to the original image. What I want is that if I zoom in on the image through an external software, I dont lose the information or the pixels. Also, after using the inbuilt zoom given by R, I am not able to see the nodes because they are getting overlapped by many others. Any way I can improve the picture quality or atleast I can see all the nodes?

Here's the link:

```
https://www.dropbox.com/s/m4rdf7ux8yeogb4/Rplot.pdf
```

The file for which I made the plot is like,

```
   "X1" "X2"
"1" 10 123
"2" 4 186
"3" 12 1959
"4" 61 882
"5" 96 431
"6" 14 1617
"7" 37 1536
"8" 17 292
"9" 17 768
"10" 17 2049
"11" 39 1437
"12" 5 25
"13" 36 592
"14" 32 855
"15" 10 1288
"16" 28 269
"17" 25 122 
"18" 142 147
"19" 792 1369
"20" 21 801
"21" 837 1004
"22" 1004 1924
"23" 515 1004
.............
"175" 356 2303
"176" 83 326
```

The code that I used to make the plot is as follows:

```
 library(igraph)
 gg7 <- graph.edgelist(cbind(as.character(wt$X1), as.character(wt$X2)), 
                 directed=F)
 sum(clusters(gg7)$csize>2)         
 plot(gg7)
```

Here, the name of the file is "wt".

Comment: Can you show us the code you used to make your plot? You'll probably get more, and more useful, help if you provide specific details about what you tried, along with a sample of any data (or fake data with the same essential structure as your real data) that went into creating the plot.

Comment: I will add that. Coming right up. :)

Comment: For starters, you could look at the help for `plot.igraph`, which describes all the various parameters and options for graph plotting with the `igraph` package. In particular, see the link on that help page to `igraph.plotting` for lots of options. Also see the help for `layout`, which allows you to select from various algorithms for node placement when drawing the graph.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the plot and layout options (see link to `igraph.plotting` on the `plot.igraph` help page and also the help for `layout`) to reduce overlap and increase readability. Also, saving your plot as a PDF file will allow you to zoom in as much as you like. Here are two example layouts with fake data. I've adjusted only the layout and the vertex size, but there are many other options.

```
library(igraph)

set.seed(20)
wt2 = data.frame(X1=sample(1:100,200,replace=TRUE), X2=sample(1:100,200,replace=TRUE))
gg7 <- graph.edgelist(cbind(as.character(wt2$X1), as.character(wt2$X2)), 
                      directed=F)       

pdf("plot.pdf",10,10)
igraph.options(plot.layout=layout.circle, vertex.size=5)
plot(gg7)
dev.off()
```

[image]

```
pdf("plot2.pdf",10,10)
igraph.options(plot.layout=layout.graphopt, vertex.size=7)
plot(gg7)
dev.off()
```

[image]